# kinit(v5): Client not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials

Tags: linux, active-directory, kerberos

Обращаюсь к вам от безысходности. Может подскажете, в какую сторону копать.

Ситуация:

Был сервер на SLES с настроенным SSO для apache через kerberos. В один прекрасный момент решили масштабироваться горизонтально и добавили еще один сервер. Заодно решили соблюсти корпоративные стандарты и завели нового технического пользователя.

На новом сервере все отлично завелось, а старый наотрез отказывается инициировать принципала. Второй день бьемся а света в конце тоннеля не видать.

Попытались вернуться к старому пользователя для конкретно этого сервера - та же петрушка.

SPN записи для старого сервера удаляли. Разные типы шифрования пробовали.

Как делали:

```
ktpass /mapUser sysmonusr /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL 
    /princ HTTP/oldserver.domain.net@DOMAIN.NET 
    /crypto DES-CBC-MD5 -pass password /out krb5.keytab /kvno 10
```

Пользователь авторизуется успешно

```
# kinit sysmonusr
    Password for sysmonusr@DOMAIN.NET:
#
```

А вот тут всегда одно и то же

```
# kinit -V -t -k HTTP/oldserver.domain.net
    kinit(v5): Client not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials

# klist -k
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  10 HTTP/oldserver.domain.net@DOMAIN.NET


# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: sysmonusr@DOMAIN.NET

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
05/18/17 14:21:20  05/19/17 00:21:37  krbtgt/DOMAIN.NET@DOMAIN.NET
    renew until 05/19/17 14:21:20
```

krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = DOMAIN.NET
        clockskew = 300
        default_keytab_name = /etc/krb5.keytab
        default_tkt_enctypes = des-cbc-md5
        default_tgs_enctypes = des-cbc-md5
        dns_lookup_realm = false
        dns_lookup_kdc = false
        allow_weak_crypto = yes

[realms]
DOMAIN.NET = {
        default_domain = domain.net
        kdc = dc1.domain.net
        kdc = dc2.domain.net
        admin_server = dc1.domain.net
        admin_server = dc2.domain.net
}
[domain_realm]
        .domain.net = DOMAIN.NET
        domain.net = DOMAIN.NET
[appdefaults]
pam = {
        ticket_lifetime = 1d
        dns_lookup_kdc = false
        renew_lifetime = 1d
        forwardable = true
        proxiable = false
        minimum_uid = 1
        external = sshd
        use_shmem = sshd
}
```

Первые десять страниц гугла по этой теме перечитал. Буду рад любым советам.

**UPD**

Попробовал ввести его в домен и запустить SSO с помощью samba. Все ввелось, никаких ошибок, но в логе апача все та же печаль "Client not found in Kerberos database "

Answer (score 1):

У меня была похожая проблема из-за длинного названия сервера. Укоротил название до восьми символов, перенастроил - все заработало.

Comment: ну да раньше то работало. Да и название меньше, чем у нового даже. Может дело не в длине, а в самом факте смены названия?